# unsigned char * - Equivalent C#

Tags: c#, c++

I am porting a library from C++ to C# but have come across a scenario I am unsure of how to resolve, which involves casting an `unsigned char *` to an `unsigned int *`.

C++

```
unsigned int c4;
unsigned int c2;
unsigned int h4;

int pos(unsigned char *p)
{
    c4 = *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned int *>(p - 4));
    c2 = *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned short *>(p - 2));
    h4 = ((c4 >> 11) ^ c4) & (N4 - 1);

    if ((tab4[h4][0] != 0) && (tab4[h4][1] == c4))
    {
        c = 256;
        return (tab4[h4][0]);
    }

    c = 257;
    return (tab2[c2]);
}
```

C# (It's wrong):

```
 public uint pos(byte p) 
 {
        c4 = (uint)(p - 4);
        c2 = (ushort)(p - 2);
        h4 = ((c4 >> 11) ^ c4) & (1 << 20 - 1);
        if ((tab4[h4, 0] != 0) && (tab4[h4, 1] == c4)) {
            c = 256;
            return (tab4[h4, 0]);
        }
        c = 257;
        return (tab2[c2]);
 }
```

I believe in the C# example, you could change `byte p` to `byte[]` but I am clueless when it would come to casting `byte[]` to a single uint value.

Additionally, could anyone please explain to me, why would you cast an `unsigned char *` to a `unsigned int *`? What purpose does it have?

Any help/push to direction would be very useful.

Comment: the pointer arithmetic that is going on with p-4 and p-2 would require to look at the calling context before we can even attempt to define a proper signature for the C# equivalent. what is the memory layout of `p` in source?

Comment: You' could use the BitConverter class.

Comment: C++/CLI is not an option on Mono, nor is it for .NET Core.

Comment: @dlatikay Thanks for your comment. The context of P is an unsigned char[1 << 26] and a whole file is read into the char[] using fread. Pos is then called in a loop x = pos(&buf[i]);

Comment: @Dan It is currently implemented using PInvoke in C# but due to the legacy code and use of static variables, doesn't currently work in a multi threaded environment. We don't want to spend time supporting it in C++.

Comment: and in that loop, `i` is skipping the first four bytes and incremented by 6? could show show part of that, I would suggest to rewrite that file parser to use a struct that reflects the layout of `Int32`s followed by `ushort`s or maybe simply have two arguments in `pos()`. I would dispute the dupehammer as we're not necessarily focused on the `reinterpret_cast` here.

Comment: @dlatikay Thank you for your ocmment. Please could you provide an example of your two argument pos method signature?

Comment: well, not really, unless the duplicate mark is undone. for now: `public uint pos(uint c4, ushort c2) { h4 = ... }`

Comment: let it flow, @πάντα ῥεῖ. we have a way to help OP without any `reinterpret_cast` mess whatsoever. It looks like a clean port without any pointer arithmetics or `unsafe` would be feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translation of the problematic lines would be:

```
int pos(byte[] a, int offset)
{
    // Read the four bytes immediately preceding offset
    c4 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(a, offset - 4);
    // Read the two bytes immediately preceding offset
    c2 = BitConverter.ToUInt16(a, offset - 2);
```

and change the call from `x = pos(&buf[i])` (which even in C++ is the same as `x = pos(buf + i)`) to

```
x = pos(buf, i);
```

An important note is that the existing C++ code is wrong as it violates the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: I just stopped short of posting my own answer when I noticed that on an architecture where the `int` in C++ would be 32 bit wide, we have an overlap. would in this case the c2 not just be the lower word of c4?

Comment: @dlatikay: Yes, it overlaps.  Does in the C++ code too.  (On architectures where C# is used, `c2` would be the higher word, not lower, but your observation is essentially correct)

Comment: Lovely clean solution. Thank you! Additionally, @dlatika thank you for your help aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing analogous functionality in C# does not need to involve code that replicates the C version on a statement-by-statement basis, especially when the original is using pointers.
When we assume an architecture where `int` is 32 bit, you could simplify the C# version like this:

```
uint[] tab2;
uint[,] tab4;
ushort c;

public uint pos(uint c4)
{
    var h4 = ((c4 >> 11) ^ c4) & (1 << 20 - 1);
    if ((tab4[h4, 0] != 0) && (tab4[h4, 1] == c4))
    {
        c = 256;
        return (tab4[h4, 0]);
    }
    else
    {
        c = 257;
        var c2 = (c4 >> 16) & 0xffff; // HIWORD
        return (tab2[c2]);
    }
}
```

This simplification is possible because c4 and c2 overlap: c2 is the high word of c4, and is needed only when the lookup in `tab4` does not match.

(The identifier `N4` was present in original code but replaced in your own translation by the expression 1<<20).

The calling code would have to loop over an array of int, which according to comments is possible. While the original C++ code starts at offset 4 and looks back, the C# equivalent would start at offset 0, which seems a more natural thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ code you are sending pointer to char, but normally C# does not working with memory using this way, you need array instead of pointer.

But you can use `unsafe` keyword to work directly with memory.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8.aspx